# git alias for force pushing to branch

Tags: git, alias

I have this command that I usually run to forcefully push my changes to a remote branch:

`git push --force origin head:{remote-branch}`

I would like to create a git alias so that I could just type

`git pfr {remote-branch}`

and achieve the same effect.

I tried adding this to my `.gitconfig` file:

`pfr = push --force origin head:`

But I got this error when I ran `git pfr {remote-branch}` to use the alias:

`fatal: invalid refspec 'head:'`

Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the alias gets expanded, and then additional arguments come after it as *separate words.*  That is, `prf` expands to:

```
push --force origin head:
```

so that the command `git pfr foo` becomes:

```
git push --force origin head: foo
```

and not the command you wanted, which was:

```
git push --force origin head:foo
```

(note the lack of a space here—the branch name `foo` is conjoined with the string `head:` as a single word).

This kind of more-fancy alias expansion requires something more powerful than Git's alias processing.  You can either give up on it, or use a shell alias.

This gets a bit tricky though.  To illustrate, here's a shell alias with the command `echo` at the front, which prints what it would do, instead of doing it:

```
prf = !echo git push --force origin head:$1
```

When I run this, it reveals the problem with this first attempt:

```
$ git prf asdf
git push --force origin head:asdf asdf
```

The `$1` expanded to the first argument, and put it in as part of the combined single-word expression, so that it became `head:asdf`.  But then the `$1` argument is repeated!  That's because Git passed the command <kbd>git push --force origin head:$1</kbd> as the command that the shell should run, then <kbd>asdf</kbd> as the first argument to that command.  The shell expanded `$1` in place and then left the argument in place as well, so that `asdf` is now repeated.

To fix this, we need to have the shell invoke a *shell function:*

```
prf = "!f() { echo git push --force origin head:$1; }; f"
```

(Because this contains other special characters, we need to quote the whole thing as well.)  Running *this* produces:

```
$ git prf asdf
git push --force origin head:asdf
```

which shows that if the `echo` is removed, it will do the right thing.

Note that if you don't supply one argument for `$1`, the shell will expand it anyway, to the empty string.  If you supply additional arguments (which would become `$2` and so on), they will be thrown away.  So overall, this alias is quite fragile and the whole approach is not a generally good one.  It's OK for your specific use case as long as you remember its limitations—but in general, instead of writing fancy aliases, you should write Git *scripts*, in which you write a complete program (in sh / bash) that detects and handles *all* of its arguments, checking for improper usage, and so on.

Last, note that you should never use lowercase `head` to refer to the current commit or branch.  You should always write it in uppercase, as `HEAD`.  You can *get away* with the lowercase variant on Windows and MacOS, but it turns out that even there, the lowercase variant behaves badly if you use `git worktree add`.  If you find typing `HEAD` too cumbersome, remember that `@` is a valid synonym, so instead of typing `HEAD` or its not-very-portable cousin `head` you can just type the one character `@`.

Comment: I must confess, I didn't really understand much beyond the fancy alias expansion explanation. To be specific, I got lost here:  "That's because Git passed the command git push --force origin head:$1 as the command that the shell should run, then asdf as the first argument to that command". But your suggestion worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your repo, open terminal and type

```
git config --local --replace-all alias.pfr "push origin -f"
```

If you want your alias to be there globally, you can use --global option.

```
git config --global --replace-all alias.pfr "push origin -f"
```

`--replace-all` just replaces any other alias named pfr previously present in config.

After this, you will be able to do:

```
git pfr branchName
```

and the corresponding branch will be force pushed to remote.

Note: Force pushing the branch to remote may be a bad idea in case your branch is being used by other colleagues, because if you rewrite history locally and force push, your peers will have a nightmare when they try to merge/rebase with your branch.

Hope this helps!